# IE: SCRIPT5009: 'e' is undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) plugin, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not IE and returns **`SCRIPT5009: 'e' is undefined`**.
JQuery dode:

```
// Initialize history plugin.
// The callback is called at once by present location.hash. 
$.historyInit(pageload, "advanced.html");

// set onlick event for buttons using the jQuery 1.3 live method
$("a[rel='history']").live('click', function () {
    if (e.button != 0) return true;

    var hash = this.href;
    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

    // moves to a new page. 
    // pageload is called at once. 
    // hash don't contain "#", "?"
    $.historyLoad(hash);

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the event parameter. Add an `e` in the function call.

```
$("a[rel='history']").live('click', function (e) {
if (e.button != 0) return true;
```